# Efficiently format dates

Tags: date, google-sheets

I am having problems getting dates to work out in a uniform manner across all cells when pulled from raw data.

Here is a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lVfdSZzKdRDUBfnc9TrZw0EfU-f2HZ2hOAOgu39-G_0/edit?usp=sharing

B: Posting the raw data.

C: Splitting to pull the numbers apart.

I: Work around the dates being formatted as "1915", instead of the desired "2015".

J: Put those numbers back together again, this was a work around to force them as a numeric vs text.

The problem you will see is data in row 7, is no longer x/xx/xx, but instead, x/x/xx.

How can I make this, so I post the raw data, and the formula automatically assumes for the small variance in dates?

If not, is there another simple solution? We will be posting this data daily, so efficiency would be ideal!

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Which result is displayed incorrectly in which cell? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just format the column and if it recognises a date it will format it as such. I went on the sheet you linked and changed column J's format (Format > Number > More Formats > More Date and Time Formats... and then *Day(5) / Month(8) / Year(1930)* as the format. Does that do what you require?